# How to open a Form as an overlay over other full screen applications?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, .net-core, overlay

I am trying to open a form as an overlay to another running application which runs in full screen mode. I am only interested to have this overlay only on top of this specific running app.

I've done some searching and I tried different behavior:

1. First I tried to set the `TopMost` property of the form as `true`:

   ```
   private void TrackerManagerOnGameStarted(object? sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       _frm = new DeckOverlayForm();
       _frm.TopMost = true;
       _frm.Show();
   }
   ```

   This didn't work at all. I see the form if I alt-tab, but it doesn't show over the running app, which I think is normal, since `TopMost` property as stated in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.topmost?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

   > A topmost form is a form that overlaps all the other **(non-topmost)** forms even if it is not the active or foreground form.

   I believe the other running app, since it's in full screen, has the priority.
2. I then tried to modify my form using Win32 Api with the following code:

   ```
   static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
   static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
   static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
   static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
   const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
   const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
   const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
   public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

   protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation => true;

   public DeckOverlayForm()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void DeckOverlayForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       SetWindowPos(this.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
   }
   ```

   This also didn't work.
3. I, then, combined the logic from point 2 with the following:

   ```
   private void TrackerManagerOnGameStarted(object? sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
       var proc = processes.First(x => x.ProcessName == PROCESS_NAME);
       NativeWindow win32Parent = new NativeWindow();
       win32Parent.AssignHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);

       _frm = new DeckOverlayForm();
       _frm.TopMost = true; //I tried with this and without it.
       _frm.Show(win32Parent);
   }
   ```

   After trying this, I can see the form for a little bit, but the application become unresponsive for a little time. I can click on buttons inside it but nothing happens. Then after like 10 to 20 seconds, the form crashes and the running app becomes fully operational again.

How can I achieve this and end up with the form showing as an overlay without problems?

Comment: What if the other application tries to set itself as topmost? Then your overlay and the other app may have an endless fight to be topmost.

Comment: To see if there's anything app-specific, have you tried your solutions with another application, like web browser, text editor, etc., or something that others can easily use to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I will try that as soon as I can and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you @RezaAghaei, you inspired me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RezaAghaei's comment I ended up figuring it out.

The way I was opening that form was after an event was being raised from a file watcher. After adding a button to open the form manually to see if it works over other applications, it worked even with the application I want it to work with.

Therefor, I tried to change the following which ended up working:

```
private void TrackerManagerOnGameStarted(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _statisticsForm?.AnnounceGameStarted();

    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
            var proc = processes.First(x => x.ProcessName == PROCESS_NAME);
            NativeWindow win32Parent = new NativeWindow();
            win32Parent.AssignHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);

            _frm = Program.ServiceProvider!.GetRequiredService<DeckOverlayForm>();
            _frm.TopMost = true;
            _frm.Show(win32Parent);
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        var proc = processes.First(x => x.ProcessName == PROCESS_NAME);
        NativeWindow win32Parent = new NativeWindow();
        win32Parent.AssignHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);

        _frm = Program.ServiceProvider!.GetRequiredService<DeckOverlayForm>(); 
        _frm.TopMost = true;
        _frm.Show(win32Parent);
    }
}
```

I wasn't getting the usual errors we get when something needs invoking, but when I made sure to check if invoke is required, it worked like a charm.